# How do I call a subfunction from another subfunction of an object in PHP?

Tags: php

How would I call a subfunction from another subfunction of an object in php, like this:

```
class Object {
     function Function1(){
          return doSomething(data);
     }

     function Function3(){
          function Function2(){
               Function1(data);
          }
     }
}
```

?

I am trying that and my error is `Fatal error: Call to undefined function convertMonthStringtoNumber()`, with `convertMonthStringtoNumber()` being `Function1()` in the example code.

Comment: I believe this.Function1(); will give you what you need. console.log(this); in the class and in the function to see what it gives you,

Comment: You need to do `$this->convertMonthStringtoNumber();`

Comment: @ShanRobertson console.log? This isn't Javascript.

Comment: soooorrrrrrrrrrry grand master @Mike. print $this; then.

Comment: I got the question a bit wrong. Knowing `$this->convertMonthStringtoNumber()` is valuable, however. I had to update the question after realizing this wasn't the answer...

Comment: Seems like very bad/complicated design to me.

Comment: It's actually so I can organize a lot of code and sort through it much more easily in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I just had to call the Object class for `Function1()`

Thus, I did this and it worked, although I don't completely understand PHP encapsulation.

```
class Object {
     function Function1(){
          return doSomething(data);
     }

     function Function3(){
          function Function2(){
               Object::Function1(data);
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but there is no encapsulation at all involved in your examples - there are no fields at all! Seems like you just want to [namespace your functions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php).

Plus you are calling a non-static method statically [the double-colon] notation, and that should be avoided as well.

Comment: Does encapsulation only apply to data? What would you recommend instead?

Comment: See my link about namespacing, after having some nice read about OOP in general possibly!

Answer (score 3):

You can call through the [`$this` psuedo-variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php).

```
$this->Function1();
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to access instance methods as `$this -> methodName()`, e.g.

```
class Object {
     function Function1(){
     }

     function Function2(){
          $this -> Function1();
     }

}
```

Comment: It's slightly more complicated. I updated the question. It's a function (function2) inside of a function (function3) inside of the object that's calling function1